# Validators, password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, password-confirmation

I can't figure out why the model doesen't check for the password confirmation, this is the code of the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  validates :email, :presence =>true,
                    :uniqueness=>true
  validates :password, :presence =>true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 40 },
                    :confirmation =>true
  validates_confirmation_of :password
end
```

The controller is intended take the data from the view and try to perform a save, this is the code of the view:

```
<h1>Registration process</h1>
<%= form_for(@new_user) do |f|%>
<% if @new_user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@new_user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @new_user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %><br />
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%#TODO Confirm password%>

    <%= f.submit 'Join' %>
<%end%>
```

No errors come out if the password doesn't match.

Comment: Do you need the double confirmation validation? You specify `:confirmation => true` in the password's validation.

Comment: Yeah...the code works for me too (as Chamnap said) and having a double  password_confirmation validator shouldn't be the reason for it not to work., it just would give you twice a message "Password doesn't match confirmation"

Answer (score 36):

I just got burned by this one too.  I suspect your confirmation value is `nil`.  From the docs:

> NOTE: This check is performed only if
>   password_confirmation is not nil, and
>   by default only on save. To require
>   confirmation, make sure to add a
>   presence check for the confirmation
>   attribute:

- [Ruby on Rails API: validates_confirmation_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_confirmation_of)

Also, you don't need `attr_accessor :password_confirmation`, since the validation adds it for you.  Rails!

Comment: Thanks - this was giving me some heartburn as well!

Comment: how can i make the confirmation NOT nil?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mass assignment than you need to add password to `attr_accessible`.
`attr_accessor` will create a virtual attribute but the same will not be available for mass assignment
Idealy we should not be adding `password_confirmation` to the `attr_accessible`, `validates_confirmation_of` should validate the value of `password` and `password_confirmation` but the value of `password_confirmation` is coming nill. I added `password_confirmation` to attr_accessible and it works properly

Working with Rails 3.